# correct syntax for making an array of SDL_Textures and passing it to a function in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sdl-2

I'm trying to create an array of textures in main, then pass it into a function for use.

I can't figure out the correct way to pass a pointer to this array, or whether I've written the array wrong.

To add an extra layer of confusion, I read that the data type SDL_Texture which I'm using needs a double pointer as it's contents are only accessible internally by the library.

In summary please can someone tell me the correct syntax for creating and passing an array of this data type.

test code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

//function that places array of textures across top of window
void processTexture(SDL_Renderer *renderer,
                    int arElements,
                    SDL_Texture *textureArray //correct pointer?
                    )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arElements; ++i)
    {
        SDL_Rect textureRect = {i*10, 0, 10, 10}; //rectangle for placing textures

        //problem area?
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,
                       *textureArray[i], //correct pointer?
                       NULL,
                       textureRect
                       );
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //set up, ignore this
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("test",
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                          100,
                                          100,
                                          0
                                          );
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,
                                                -1,
                                                0
                                                );

    SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load("test.png");
    SDL_Texture *testTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    //create single element test array, also problem area?
    int arElements = 1;                     //number of textures to place in array
    SDL_Texture textureArray[arElements];   //array of data type SDL_Texture with arElements number of elements. correct syntax?
    textureArray[0] = *testTexture;         //array element contains pointer to texture. correct syntax?

    //call function that uses array of textures
    processTexture(renderer,
                   arElements,
                   &textureArray //correct pointer?
                   );

    //clean up, ignore this
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

errors:

```
In function 'processTexture':|
17|error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct SDL_Texture'|
17|error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'SDL_Texture {aka struct SDL_Texture}'|
19|error: incompatible type for argument 4 of 'SDL_RenderCopy'|
870|note: expected 'const SDL_Rect * {aka const struct SDL_Rect *}' but argument is of type 'SDL_Rect {aka struct SDL_Rect}'|
In function 'SDL_main':|
48|error: array type has incomplete element type 'SDL_Texture {aka struct SDL_Texture}'|
48|warning: unused variable 'textureArray' [-Wunused-variable]|
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array has the wrong type. `SDL_Texture` is an opaque type, so end-users cannot hold them by value (or dereference pointers to them, same thing), only by pointer.

```cpp
SDL_Texture textureArray[arElements]
```

That should be an array of `SDL_Texture*`.

---

You have problems passing pointers both to your own function and to SDL from there.

```cpp
//function that places array of textures across top of window
void processTexture(SDL_Renderer *renderer,
                    int arElements,
                    SDL_Texture *textureArray //correct pointer?
                    )
```

This should take a pointer to the 1st element of the array, to enable indexing / pointer arithmetic to get to the other elements. Take an `SDL_Renderer**`.

```cpp
//call function that uses array of textures
processTexture(renderer,
               arElements,
               &textureArray //correct pointer?
               );
```

`&textureArray` is a pointer to the whole array, but your function (now) wants a pointer to the 1st element. Write `&textureArray[0]`, or just `textureArray` and let the decay-to-pointer handle it.

---

```cpp
//problem area?
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,
               *textureArray[i], //correct pointer?
               NULL,
               textureRect
               );
```

You can't write `*textureArray[i]` in user code, because it's an opaque type, and thus you can't dereference it. Thus, SDL doesn't want a value here, but rather a pointer. So, pass `textureArray[i]` i.e. `*(textureArray + i)`, i.e. the `i`th element (which itself is a pointer).

Comment: Regarding _Just pass `textureArray[i]` i.e. `textureArray + i`_,   If `textureArray[i]` is equivalent to `*(textureArray + 1)`? how is it also equivalent to `textureArray + 1`

Comment: @ryyker Edited and hopefully fixed?

Comment: Thank you so much! that works perfectly and you are a wonderful human being.